# Maven - Profile&Modules - Activation by property?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

Could someone help me understand this issue below? Approach #1 below works as expected, when the IDE asks maven to build the project it rebuilds moduleA and include it as a dependency; everybody happy. Approach #2 which is what I want to use does not behave the same way, myProperty is a system property I've defined and toggling it between true/false does activate the profile BUT it does not build moduleA, why?

#1

```
...
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>testProfile</id>
      <activation>
         <activationByDefault>true</activationByDefault>
      </activation>
   </profile>
   <modules>
      <module>../moduleA</module>
   </modules>
</profiles>
...
```

#2

```
...
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>testProfile</id>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>myProperty</name>
            <value>true</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
   </profile>
   <modules>
      <module>../moduleA</module>
   </modules>
</profiles>
...
```

Comment: Having modules included/activated based on profiles is going the wrong path. The question is why do you need to activate/deactivate a module based on a property which not having the module active all the time?

Comment: Regardless of right or wrong what is going on here that makes #2 break?

Comment: For such question is necessary to have a full working example project which shows the issue.... otherwise its soothsaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, after hours up and down the documentation I found my problem. Was not aware that the name of the config file mattered, so I had named it **jvm.config** as I saw the bash script looked after such a file for maven options. Apparently it was supposed to be in **maven.config**